# How to send data to particular listening channel on client side using Django channels, when data is posted through REST?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Here is the scenario.
I have an django channels app, which also consist of restapi framework (DRF) with just one view, which expects a POST call, with data.
Once I get the data on that POST endpoint I wish to notify all or particular client connected via websocket (html websocket)

So, creating an endpoint was the easiest one, and that has been achieved, and then using async_to_sync(channel_name)({}) (an example) is not being listened by the frontend client.

Any concrete working example of this please?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855417/sending-messages-to-groups-in-django-channels-2